# is it possible for xquery to run openssl commands?

Tags: openssl, xquery

I am originally looking for some xquery code that can verify that a digitally signed xml content is valid before I accept it for storage into an xml db.  But I cannot find documentation on this.

If xquery allows running filesystem executables (e.g. openssl) then that can also serve my need. if that is not possible, can anyone point me to other ways to accomplish such?

Thanks for any leads.

Comment: This _heavily_ depends on the XQuery engine you're using. An alternative might be to run a trusted local proxy taking care of the verification.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your processor.

1. Some processors provide Cryptographic extension functions for XQuery e.g. http://expath.org/spec/crypto
2. Some processors provide a generic exec extension function. Such a thing could be used to run openssl commands. For example eXist-db offers `process:execute`.

Comment: *"Some processors provide a generic exec extension function..."* - Ah, more Turing machines. The hackers thank them :)